# How to ignore typescript errors with webpack?

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

My team has been using Angular1 and gulp/systemJS/jspm for several years now. We have been trying to use more Angular2-like features with ngforward (and TypeScript). I've been trying to slowly begin the transition to webpack for our team, but I'm getting a ton of TypeScript compile errors when I try to build. Probably around 1,000, or something crazy like that. They're easy to resolve; errors like not writing "import angular from 'angular'". So, eventually, we hope to go back and fix all of these.

With our current build system, despite these errors, we can run our code without a problem. To follow the previous example, Angular might be exposed as a global and we ignored the Angular import in certain files (unfortunately). Is there any way for Webpack to be able to compile our files while we're in the process of fixing them?

Comment: There are some TypeScript errors for incompatible types that can be ignored, but other TypeScript errors won't output JavaScript. You won't be able to tell which is which so if you ignore them you won't know if what you're running was really build properly.  You should read up on technical debt and the costs of delaying this kind of work until later.